# POST request with updating json file using create-react-app

Tags: node.js, ajax, reactjs, express, react-router

I'm making a project using create-react-app. There is a configured server and so on. I'm using react-router-dom for routing in my app. There is 'Comments' component. When it starts render itself it goes to my local json file and takes comments from there using ajax. When user clicks 'submit' It sends POST request with form's fields to the same json file. I have code for adding a new object to my json file. It should work when user in '/api/comments' route . This is the code for adding a new object to my json file (requires express):

```
`app.post('/api/comments', function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile(COMMENTS_FILE, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      process.exit(1);
    }
    var comments = JSON.parse(data);
    var newComment = {
      id: Date.now(),
      author: req.body.author,
      text: req.body.text,
    };
    comments.push(newComment);
    fs.writeFile(COMMENTS_FILE, JSON.stringify(comments, null, 4), 
function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
      }
      res.json(comments);
    });
  });
});`
```

But I don't know where I shoud  put this code if I'm using 'create-react-app' and it uses it's own configured server (as far I know). Maybe there is  a way to change server which 'create-react-app' uses and put there this code to handle this route? Or maybe there is a way to handle this route using 'react-router'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly the code you have posted here is server side code.  The app you have made using create-react-app is a front end application and therefore does not have any server side code.  You could however host a second server that would expose the api routes you need and then call into that server using a http library like axios.

Comment: I just found out [here](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/using-create-react-app-with-a-server/) that 'create-react-app' uses webpack dev-server and I need to use "concurrently" library to load 2 servers at once. First should be webpack's dev-server and the second one should be my API sever. But I'm not sure which of these 2 ways to choose.  Axios any better than this one?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a `create-react-app` and `express` as my api server.  Setting up `express` to run alongside `webpack-dev-server` is a supported feature of `create-react-app`.

I use `npm-run-all` to fire-up both the client and proxy express api server in my start-up script defined in `package.json`.  Here is what I believe is all that I needed to do:

1. In my `webpack.config.dev.json` file I defined a proxy setting in the `devServer` json block.  Specifically:
   `proxy: { "/api": "http://localhost:3001" },`
2. In my `package.json` file I configured a start script that uses `npm-run-all` to fire up *both* the `react-app` and `express` simultaneously.
3. I use `server.js` to fire-up express; this is where I store the equivalent of the code you outlined in your question.